# How to Convert object of arraylist to JsonObject in android?

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I am beginner in Android. I need to know

1)**How to convert object of array to JsonObject**. I need in this format

```
{"House_id":"1"
 "Date":"12.12.2016"
[{"Name":"RickBald","email":"xyz@gmail.com","address":"homeaddress1"},{"Name":"EshaRan","email":"ghj@gmail.com","address":"homeaddress2"},{"Name":"Hansa Bella","email":"sas@gmail.com","address":"homeaddress3"}...]}
```

2)**what should be the request in `volley`**,If i want **to send** this `**jsonArray**.

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you show your objects in code?

Comment: Learn [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and post the code which prepares array of objects.

Comment: Thanks @ Shashanth.

Comment: @ TruongHieu i got the proper code from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25013255/converting-arraylist-to-json-android. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you first declare arrays :

```
 String[] name ={"yousuf" , "Mohammed" , "Ali" , "Hamood" , "Alex"};
 String[] emails = {"yousuf@dd" , "Mohammed@dd" , "Ali@dd" , "Hamood@dd" , "Alex@dd"};
```

any arrays with data ,

then you create JSONArray

```
 JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
```

then you make loop to add objects to the array :

```
for (int i =0; (i < name.length) && (i < emails.length) ; i++ ) {
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
        try {
            object.put("name", name[i]);
            object.put("email" , emails[i]);
            array.put(object);
        }catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

then you can print the results in the console :

```
 Log.d("Json is " , array.toString());
```

you will get the result like this :

```
[{"name":"yousuf","email":"yousuf@dd"},{"name":"Mohammed","email":"Mohammed@dd"},{"name":"Ali","email":"Ali@dd"},{"name":"Hamood","email":"Hamood@dd"},{"name":"Alex","email":"Alex@dd"}]
```

but you can format it by : 
[Json formatter and validator](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)

and you'll have nice look to the data : 
[image]

here is the whole code:

```
public void getDataInJsonFormat (){
    String[] name ={"yousuf" , "Mohammed" , "Ali" , "Hamood" , "Alex"};
    String[] emails = {"yousuf@dd" , "Mohammed@dd" , "Ali@dd" , "Hamood@dd" , "Alex@dd"};

    JSONArray array = new JSONArray();

    for (int i =0; (i < name.length) && (i < emails.length) ; i++ ) {
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
        try {
            object.put("name", name[i]);
            object.put("email" , emails[i]);
            array.put(object);
        }catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    Log.d("Json is " , array.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) which has converters from and to JSON representations of your Java models.

Answer (score 1):

You can use GSON lib and Jackson Object mapper

Please see below code for GSON :

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
```

T is generic class (DTO class) in below method getJSONString.

```
String convertedJson = getJSONString(DTO)

public String getJSONString(T dto){
        return gson.toJson(dto);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose Your response String or JSON String

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(strResponse);
Json.putString("Name","RickBald")
```

put all the value in `jsonObject` like `Json.putString("Name","RickBald");`

And it convert into jsonArray

```
 JSONArray jsonarr = new JSONArray();
 jsonarr.put(json);
```

**OutPut:**

```
[{"Name":"RickBald","email":"xyz@gmail.com","address":"homeaddress1"},{"Name":"EshaRan","email":"ghj@gmail.com","address":"homeaddress2"},{"Name":"Hansa Bella","email":"sas@gmail.com","address":"homeaddress3"}...]
```

Comment: `json.put("Name","RickBald")` not _`Json.putString("Name","RickBald")`_